# make dynamic title linked to text box

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

Does anyone know how to link a title to whatever is in a text box? in real time, not intervals, like the title is whatever is in the text box, the instant it is typed, at the very least within a tenth of a second

Edit: @K.Deo thank you for your code! It works

only one tag needed to be edited, and slightly.

```html
<script>
    function updateTitle(text){
      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = text;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <title id='title'>My Title</title>

  <input type='text' name='sometext' onKeyUp='updateTitle(this.value)' />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Have a look into How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have some javascript at the top with a function to update the title on the page, and on keyup, call the function with the value entered.

Example:

```
<head>
  <script>
    function updateTitle(text){
      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = text;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id='title'>My Title</h1>

  <input type='text' name='sometext' onKeyUp='updateTitle(this.value)' />
```

Let me know if this is what you meant.

Comment: Almost perfect. All I had to do was replace <h1> with <title>. Thank you.